# How can i export a .jar file in Eclipse with sources

Tags: java

I have problem with exporting my work in eclipse. When i export it does not export
with everything that is in src folder. In my program I am reading things from src folder but when i export the program it won't export with the files. I am trying to export it as a runnable jar.

Comment: Quite simple answer.. but no point giving it.. See comment above ^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you provide some more input? Are you trying to export the jar as a Runnable Jar then it doesn't export by default. Otherwise on the first step when trying to export you can select the files you wish to export.

Comment: I am trying to export as a runnable jar.

Comment: I haven't tried with an runnable jar but try exporting as a normal jar and follow next--next steps , wherein in one you can provide your main class file which will be inserted in the Meta-inf. Try that, that shall work for sure.